# Interpolate matrix of complex numbers

Tags: python, image-processing, fft, interpolation, complex-numbers

I have want to rotate a row of complex numbers (which actually is a 1D FFT of a line of the Radon transform), I use `imrotate` in Matlab but I don't think the interpolation is doing what it should.

The goal is to reproduce the conversion from Radon to image space with the Projection-slice theorem.

[image]
<sup>(Image from Wikipedia)</sup>

I need to take each row of the Radon transform and rotate it according to its angle and put it at the corresponding angle in a 2D matrix. Once this is done I can get the 2D `ifft2` to recover the image (in theory). This is the goal. Anyone can help?

I thought using `imrotate`, but maybe that isn't the right thing? The goal is to map the FFT'd rows of the Radon transform to their correct position in a circle as shown in the figure above.

This is the actual result with rotate and nearest neighbour interpolation. The result on the right should be the usual SheppLogan phantom.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.data import shepp_logan_phantom
from skimage.transform import radon, rescale
from skimage.transform import iradon
from skimage.transform import rotate
import cv2 


x=shepp_logan_phantom()
x=cv2.resize(x, (128,128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
theta=np.linspace(0,180,len(x))
R=radon(x,theta)

temp_=np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)
fullFft2D=np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)

for i in range(len(theta)):
    temp_[63,:]=np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(R[:,i])).T
    fft_real=rotate(np.real(temp_),theta[i],order=0)
    fft_imag=rotate(np.imag(temp_),theta[i],order=0)
    fullFft2D += fft_real+1j*fft_real
    temp_=np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)


plt.imshow(np.fft.fftshift(np.abs(np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fullFft2D)))))
```

I have implemented what you (@Luengo) said as:

```
res=np.zeros((128,128))
tmp_=np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)
for i in range(len(theta)):
    kspace_row = np.fft.fftshift(np.fft.fft(R[:,i])).T
    tmp_[63,:] = kspace_row
    res +=  rotate(np.abs(np.fft.ifft(np.fft.fftshift(tmp_))),-theta[i])

plt.imshow(res)
```

But it doesn't work (I m probably missing something?)

Comment: I think you should rotate with nearest neighbor interpolation, otherwise you'll get weird artifacts. But really, you'll get weird artifacts no matter what. This method should work in the continuous domain, in theory. But in the discrete domain, in practice, it's just not really doable. Instead of IFT(sum(rotate(FrequencyDomainLine))), which is what  you are trying to do, compute sum(rotate(IFT(FrequencyDomainLine))), which is identical by virtue of the IFT commuting with the summation and the rotation operators. This latter computation is exactly what back projection implements!

Comment: I did try rotate with 'nearest' but i does not work. I don't understand why you add a sum? when you say sum(rotate(IFT(FrequencyDomainLine))) ? I want to place a line (at the correct angle) to create my 2D fft and then ifft it. Your sum is producing a scalar... could you develop please (and thanks for you contribution, I appreciate!)

Comment: The sum is over the various 1D FrequencyDomainLines. You add up the contributions at each projection angle.

Comment: Sorry still don't understand. sum(.) produces a scalar? (I do not see what I could do with this scalar)

Comment: I need a vector (row) which I can place in the 2D fft as shown on the picture I uploaded now

Comment: My expressions above were meant to be math, not MATLAB code. Where I said "sum", think of an uppercase sigma symbol, summing over the angle phi.

Comment: aha so you are actually summing spatial domain rows !?

Comment: rotated ifft'd rows

Comment: and each time the rest is expected to be 0 except the currently rotated row?

Comment: Indeed. Each row is placed in an image filled with zeros, rotated, then added together. The result you show, is the left-side figure a complex-valued image? Did you apply the usual filter needed in back projection? Note that by adding these lines together, you obtain a much more dense frequency-domain image near the middle than towards the edges. The |f| filtering (wedge filter) makes the density of data uniform across the frequency domain.

Comment: there is no filter applied, but still I was expecting to see at least something looking like a phantom (but of course blurry, much brighter and "glowing")

Comment: Oh, if you rotate the IFFT'd rows, do the same thing: place the row in an otherwise zero-valued image, then compute the IFFT. You'll see that the row is replicated across all rows this way. The resulting image is easy to rotate.

Comment: I recommend that you post a [mre], so we can ensure we're actually talking about the same things. It's hard to discuss implementations in comments like this. :)

Comment: ok great, please give me 2 seconds -

Comment: here is the code, I switched to Python

Comment: what do you think?

Comment: with Python I cannot directly rotate a complex matrix (unless you know how?!) so I had to separate real and imag parts and reassemble

Comment: Use `np.fft.ifft2` instead of `np.fft.ifft` in that latest code. It's a 2D image that you want to inverse transform. I just tried that and it looks OK, except it's missing the filtering.

Comment: oh wow yes it does look like the unfiltered image indeed !

Comment: thanks for the help, if you are ok, i d like to discuss it a bit more... now how can you justify your approach w.r.t. the Fourier slice theorem ?

Comment: and what about the filtering ?

Comment: I'll write an answer. I'm trying to figure out one little detail...

Comment: thanks, great ! I m looking forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rotating a single line in a 2D discrete image is really hard. You always end up with a rough approximation, interpolation doesn't help much.

The process you intend to follow is (I've added the filtering):

- For each projection in the Radon transform:

  - apply the FFT
  - apply the wedge filter
  - write this as a row though the origin of a 2D complex image
  - rotate this image to match the orientation of the projection
  - accumulate the result in an output frequency-domain image by summation
- Apply the 2D IFFT to the frequency-domain image to obtain the reconstructed image

Because we know that the IFFT operation commutes with the summation, it is possible to move the IFFT operation into the loop:

- For each projection in the Radon transform:

  - apply the FFT
  - apply the wedge filter
  - write this as a row though the origin of a 2D complex image
  - rotate this image to match the orientation of the projection
  - Apply the 2D IFFT
  - accumulate the result in an output spatial-domain image by summation

Also the rotation and the IFFT operations commute, so the above is identical to:

- For each projection in the Radon transform:

  - apply the FFT
  - apply the wedge filter
  - write this as a row though the origin of a 2D complex image
  - Apply the 2D IFFT
  - rotate this image to match the orientation of the projection
  - accumulate the result in an output spatial-domain image by summation

In this latter case, we are rotating a spatial-domain image that is smooth; it is not a single line drawn in an otherwise empty image, it is a fully band-limited function that can be interpolated into properly. The rotation result is much better in this case.

This latter process is almost the same as what the back projection algorithm does. We can further realize that the 2D IFFT of an image with a single row of data through the origin (the rest of the image is all zero) is the same as taking a 1D IFFT, and replicating that across all rows of the image. This saves quite a bit of computation.

---

Here is some code. The first method would be (a few fixes from OP's code, but the output is still not recognizable!):

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.io import imread
from skimage.data import shepp_logan_phantom
from skimage.transform import radon, rescale
from skimage.transform import iradon
from skimage.transform import rotate
import cv2 

x = shepp_logan_phantom()
x = cv2.resize(x, (128,128), interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
theta = np.linspace(0, 180, len(x), endpoint=False)
R = radon(x, theta)

filter = np.abs(np.fft.fftfreq(128))

fullFft2D = np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)
for i in range(len(theta)):
    temp_ = np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)
    temp_[64,:] = np.fft.fftshift(filter * np.fft.fft(R[:,i]))
    fft_real = rotate(np.real(temp_), theta[i], order=0, center=(64,64))
    fft_imag = rotate(np.imag(temp_), theta[i], order=0, center=(64,64))
    fullFft2D += fft_real + 1j*fft_imag

y = np.fft.ifft2(np.fft.ifftshift(fullFft2D))
plt.imshow(np.fft.fftshift(y.real)); plt.show()
```

Fixes include: (1) The origin in the `fftshift`ed frequency domain of size 128 is at 64, not 63. (2) The rotation is explicitly performed around the origin. (3) OP had a typo: `fft_real + 1j* fft_real`. (4) Added the wedge filtering. (5) Not including 180 degrees in the Radon transform (as it's identical to 0 degrees). (6) Using the real part of the IFFT, not the absolute value.

When computing through the frequency domain, if you expect a real-valued result but get non-trivial (trivial==almost zero) imaginary component, something is wrong. In the code above, the imaginary component is non-trivial. This is the result of the rotation of data that cannot be interpolated into properly. The rotation just destroys the changes of success.

The latter method would be:

```py
y = np.zeros((128,128))
for i in range(len(theta)):
    tmp_ = np.zeros((128,128)).astype(np.complex128)
    tmp_[0,:] = filter * np.fft.fft(R[:,i])
    y += rotate(np.fft.ifft2(tmp_).real, -theta[i], center=(64,64))

plt.imshow(y); plt.show()
```

This code is simplified somewhat because we don't need to use `fftshift`, we can write the line directly in the origin as expected by the FFT (row 0). The result produced reproduces the phantom correctly.

Comment: This is simply a fantastic answer. I could not have hoped better.

Comment: Still 1 question if i may: the wedge filter has a value 0 for freqency 0 (the DC component) that seems strange ?

Comment: @Machupicchu: Yes, it should probably have a value of `1/length(theta)` to preserve the mean intensity. I didn’t bother with that detail... I also didn’t bother getting the scaling right. It’s easy enough to apply some contrast stretch to the output, just like `imshow` does.

Comment: I don't want to bother you but if you're interested to think about it, I have another question related to deep learning with images in Fourier space with convolutions